# TCP_KEEPINTVL and TCP_KEEPCNT not defined in tcp.h in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp, keep-alive, darwin

I've hit a brick wall trying to enable tcp keep alive packets on a socket. This is defined in tcp.h line 201:

```
#define TCP_KEEPALIVE           0x10    /* idle time used when SO_KEEPALIVE is enabled */
```

...but the TCP_KEEPINTVL and TCP_KEEPCNT aren't there, and I haven't found a man page yet that mentions them. Are these defined somewhere else and possibly named something else? Are they disabled for iOS?

Comment: Can you have a look at netinet/tcp_timer.h? I don't have IOS headers available, but it's certainly possible that it is not supported in IOS. The manpage tcp(7) should be where they are mentioned, if they are supported.

Comment: The three TCP options keepcount, keepidle, and keepintvl are specified only on a _per-system_ basis; on many systems they can be found in /proc and permanently set in /etc/sysctl.conf. Providing them as _per-application_ variables is an _extension_  ...which many modern desktop OSs provide. I strongly suspect (but am not certain) this extension is simply not supported by iOS.

Answer (score 1):

They are certainly defined in iOS 7 and OS X 10.9 (and probably earlier).

```
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
```

However, I've found a post on the Apple dev forums which suggests that it's not actually implemented.